# Javascript multiple occurrences of the keywords

Tags: javascript

I have a text which contains some keywords followed by sentences like,

```
var data = "Name The United States of America (USA), commonly referred to as the United States (U.S.) or America, is a federal republic composed of 50 states, the federal district of Washington, D.C., five major territories, and various possessions. **About** 48 contiguous states and Washington, D.C., are in central North America between Canada and Mexico. The state of Alaska is in the northwestern part of North America and the state of Hawaii is an archipelago in the mid-Pacific. The territories are scattered **about** the Pacific Ocean and the Caribbean Sea. At 3.8 million square miles and with over 320 million people, the country is the world's third largest by total area and the third most populous. It is one of the world's most ethnically diverse and multicultural nations, the product of large-scale immigration from many countries. Life The geography and climate of the United States are also extremely diverse, and the country is home to **about** a wide variety of wildlife. Rest USA is a diversified nation and Niagara is world famous.";
```

In the above text, there are 4 keywords - Name, About,Life, Rest. I want to separate the text that follow these keywords into separate string arrays and populate them. The order in which these keywords appear in the text is always the same. I have tried the following code so far:

```
var name = [];
var about = [];
var life = [];
function transform_report(data) {
    var keywords = ["Name", "About", "Life", "Rest"];
    var output_data = "Event ";
    var keyword_index = 0;
    var input_data = data.toString();
    var pos = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
        pos = input_data.indexOf(keywords[i]);
        if (pos != -1) {
            keyword_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    while (pos != -1) {
        output_data += keywords[keyword_index] + " : ";
        pos += keywords[keyword_index].length;
        var index = keyword_index;
        keyword_index = find_next_keyword(keywords, keyword_index, input_data, pos);
        var end_pos = input_data.indexOf(keywords[keyword_index]);
        var output_text = input_data.slice(pos, end_pos).replace(/:/, '');

        output_data += output_text.trim() + "\n";
        if (keywords[index] === "Name") {
            name.push(output_text.trim());
        }
        if ((keywords[index] === "About")) {
            about.push(output_text.trim());
        }
        if ((keywords[index] === "Life")) {
            life.push(output_text.trim());
        }
        pos = end_pos;
    }
    return output_data;
}

function find_next_keyword(keywords, index, input_data, pos) {
    var orig_index = index;
    var min_pos = input_data.length;
    var min_index = index;
    if (index == keywords.length - 1)
        return -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
        if (i == orig_index)
            continue;
        var keyword = keywords[i];
        var next_keyword_pos = input_data.indexOf(keyword, pos);
        if (next_keyword_pos != -1 && next_keyword_pos < min_pos) {
            min_pos = next_keyword_pos;
            min_index = i;
        }
    }
    return min_index;
}
```

The above code works fine when the keywords appear only once in the data. But in this case, the keyword "About" appears also as a word in the sentences that should be put in "about array" and "life array". The output should be:

```
name array contains :
The United States of America (USA), commonly referred to as the United States (U.S.) or America, is a federal republic composed of 50 states, the federal district of Washington, D.C., five major territories, and various possessions. 

about array contains: 48 contiguous states and Washington, D.C., are in central North America between Canada and Mexico. The state of Alaska is in the northwestern part of North America and the state of Hawaii is an archipelago in the mid-Pacific. The territories are scattered about the Pacific Ocean and the Caribbean Sea. At 3.8 million square miles and with over 320 million people, the country is the world's third largest by total area and the third most populous. It is one of the world's most ethnically diverse and multicultural nations, the product of large-scale immigration from many countries. 

life array contains:The geography and climate of the United States are also extremely diverse, and the country is home to about a wide variety of wildlife.
```

But since the keyword appears as a normal word, I am not getting the required output. Are there any ways to do this in Javascript? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: have you considered using String.prototype.split()?

Comment: Could you please me know where to split it and how will it solve the multiple occurrences problem? Thanks.

Comment: why did you exclude `Rest` array from the result?

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: I will not need the Rest array for further processing. So I left it out. If we put that also into a separate array, there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your condition:

> "... . The order in which these keywords appear in the text is always the
>   same."

the "main goal" can be achieved with the following approach using `String.split`, `String.replace`, `String.substring` and `Array.indexOf` functions:

```
// data is the initial string(text)
var splitted = data.split(/\.\s/),  // splitting sentences
    keywords = ["Name", "About", "Life", "Rest"],
    currentKeyword = "",  // the last active keyword
    keysObject = {'name' : [], 'about' : [], 'life' : [], 'rest' : []};

splitted.forEach(function(v){
    var first = v.substring(0, v.indexOf(" ")).replace(/\W/g, "");
    if (keywords.indexOf(first) !== -1) {
        keysObject[first.toLowerCase()].push(v.substring(v.indexOf(" ") + 1));
        currentKeyword = first.toLowerCase();
    } else {
        keysObject[currentKeyword].push(v);
    }    
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(keysObject, 0, 4));
```

The output:

```
{
    "name": [
        "The United States of America (USA), commonly referred to as the United States (U.S.) or America, is a federal republic composed of 50 states, the federal district of Washington, D.C., five major territories, and various possessions"
    ],
    "about": [
        "48 contiguous states and Washington, D.C., are in central North America between Canada and Mexico",
        "The state of Alaska is in the northwestern part of North America and the state of Hawaii is an archipelago in the mid-Pacific",
        "The territories are scattered **about** the Pacific Ocean and the Caribbean Sea",
        "At 3.8 million square miles and with over 320 million people, the country is the world's third largest by total area and the third most populous",
        "It is one of the world's most ethnically diverse and multicultural nations, the product of large-scale immigration from many countries"
    ],
    "life": [
        "The geography and climate of the United States are also extremely diverse, and the country is home to **about** a wide variety of wildlife"
    ],
    "rest": [
        "USA is a diversified nation and Niagara is world famous."
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly you want to start a new string at the first "About" but not the others that happen after.  I was able to do this using string search, because it finds the first instance.

> http://codepen.io/jnfr/pen/gMYbPJ

```
    <button onclick="myFunction()">button</button>

    <p id="name"></p>

    <p id="about"></p>

    <p id="life"></p>

    <p id="rest"></p>

    function myFunction() {
    var str = "Name The United States of America (USA), commonly referred to as the United States (U.S.) or America, is a federal republic composed of 50 states, the federal district of Washington, D.C., five major territories, and various possessions. About 48 contiguous states and Washington, D.C., are in central North America between Canada and Mexico. The state of Alaska is in the northwestern part of North America and the state of Hawaii is an archipelago in the mid-Pacific. The territories are scattered about the Pacific Ocean and the Caribbean Sea. At 3.8 million square miles and with over 320 million people, the country is the world's third largest by total area and the third most populous. It is one of the world's most ethnically diverse and multicultural nations, the product of large-scale immigration from many countries. Life The geography and climate of the United States are also extremely diverse, and the country is home to about a wide variety of wildlife. Rest USA is a diversified nation and Niagara is world famous."; 

   var n = str.search("About");
   var name = str.slice(0, n);


   var p = str.search("Life");
   var about = str.slice(n, p);

   var r = str.search("Rest");
   var life = str.slice(p, r);

   var rest = str.slice(r, str.length);

  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;
  document.getElementById("about").innerHTML = about;
  document.getElementById("life").innerHTML = life;
  document.getElementById("rest").innerHTML = rest;

  }
```